# if statement extremely slow in loop

Tags: c++, if-statement

If i do this...

```
vector< array<double,2> > magT(magnitude.size(), array<double,2>() );

for ( int n = 0; n < magnitude.size()-amount; n++ ) {
    for ( int chan = 0; chan < channels; chan++ ) {

        for ( int m = 0; m < amount; m++ ) {
            magT.at(n).at(chan) += magnitude.at(n+m).at(chan);
        }

        magT.at(n).at(chan) /= amount;
    }
}

magnitude = magT;
```

...its lightning fast. But if I add a couple of if statements like this...

```
vector< array<double,2> > magT(magnitude.size(), array<double,2>() );

int upper = ceil(amount/2);
int lower = floor(-amount/2);

for ( int n = 0; n < magnitude.size(); n++ ) {
    for ( int chan = 0; chan < channels; chan++ ) {

        for ( int m = lower; m < upper; m++ ) {
            m = n+m < 0 ? 0 : m;
            m = n+m > magnitude.size()-1 ? 0 : m;
            magT.at(n).at(chan) += magnitude.at(n+m).at(chan);
        }

        magT.at(n).at(chan) /= amount;
    }
}

magnitude = magT;
```

...its *hundreds* of times slower, maybe thousands. Are logical statements really this slow? Should i be keeping them out of nested loops like this? If so, how do i accomplish something like this reasonably?

Comment: That's because you have conditions to reset the `for` loop (`m = 0;`) **not** because of the `if` statements.

Comment: You also can calculate `magnitude.size()` outside all of the for loops. Anything that can be calculated outside a triple nested for loop should be.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of slownes here might be the design of processor pipeline. Usually processor predicts future instructions (and starts its), but if predictor was wrong, everything became slow (since processor have to forgot pre-calculated results).

So it is better to avoid 'if' instructions in loops.

Sometimes it is better to write
  m = (n+m < 0) ? 0 : m;
instead of
  if (n+m < 0) m = 0;
(here everything depends on optimization options of your compiler, so sometimes this recomendation does not work).